# How to animate wedge angle changes in iOS

Tags: iphone, animation, quartz-2d

I have a cricle of constant size and a wedge inside of the circle that rotates around the center (like a radar). Radius of that wedge is also constant, but angle of the wedge changes. It can be several degrees and it can be 360.

The wedge is implemented using UIView derived class and Quartz 2D and I can easily animate the rotation using *UIView animateWithDuration* and *CGAffineTransformMakeRotation*. Now I am looking for a way to animate the wedge angle changes, with expanding/collapsing showing symmetrically on both sides from axis of the wedge (like if you are opening a fan). I would like to have easing, too.

Can anybody provide any pointers or examples?

Thanks!

Comment: How angle is changing? Is it according to user touch?